# How to avoid repeating code in common table expressions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
WITH 
cte1 AS
   (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM (<Query1>) t1) ,
cte2 AS
   (<Query1>)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cte2.id)
  FROM cte1
    LEFT JOIN cte2 ON <various conditions>
```

Is there any way to avoid repeating `<Query1>` in both common table expressions ?

Comment: You could create a temp table, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SomeTableName <Query1> and select from that.

Comment: The query cannot look like your pseudo code, because it is allowed to have only one `with` keyword. And the question is not clear: you can define your `<Query1>` as CTE (what you did in CTE2), so what is the question?

Comment: Your sample code -- even if syntactically correct -- is not doing anything useful.  There may be better ways to implement what you want, but it is not clear what you are really trying to do.

Comment: @astentx sorry that was a typo. Corrected now

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is related to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67534701/how-to-avoid-repeating-code-in-common-table-expressions-in-mysql) when I came to implement Akina's answer. In that other question, the source table `dt` is in fact a rather large query of several other tables, so I had to write something like you see in this question in order to make it work (and it does work correctly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already almost doing it. Rephrase the query as:

```
WITH
cte2 AS
   (<Query1>),
cte1 AS
   (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM cte2)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cte2.id)
FROM cte1
LEFT JOIN cte2 ON <various conditions>
```